# Django prevent migrations on remote database

Tags: python, django, django-models, multiple-databases, django-database

I have a Django app that connects to two databases. One of my DBs is on a different (production) server. I want to make very sure that in developing my app, I don't accidentally migrate models on the production server. My understanding is this: Suppose my settings.py DATABASES is this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'remote_db': {
        'NAME'    : 'important_remote_db_name',
        'ENGINE'  : 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER'    : 'someuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'somepass',
        'HOST'    : 'some.production.host.com',
        'PORT'    : '3306',
    },
    'myapp_db': {
        'NAME'    : 'my_app_db_name',
        'ENGINE'  : 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER'    : 'localuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'localpassword'
    }
}
```

Now suppose I also have a router class called RemoteDBRouter. Like all routers, that class will have a method allow_migrate. Note that the remote DB uses Django auth models, so the User model will have app_label 'auth', and the remote DB also has its own models with app_label 'remoteapp'. With that info, I see two possibilities for the allow_migrate method:

```
#OPTION 1
def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    if app_label == 'auth' or app_label == 'remoteapp':
        return db == 'remote_db'
    return None

#OPTION 2
def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    if app_label == 'auth' or app_label == 'remoteapp':
        return False
    return None
```

Which one should I use? Option 2 is easier in that it just says that I should not migrate any models where the app_label says the models are from the remote DB. Option 1 does an additional check to see if  the db field is 'remote_db' (I assume that we need to check 'remote_db' and not 'remote_db_name'). Does it matter which one I use? I'm concerned that if I use Option 1 and the db check fails, the method will return None and then the Django code will check the next router class where allow_migrate may return True.

Comment: Why don't you just dump the remote DB into your local one every once in a while?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the `RemoteDBRouter` to be authoritative for `remote_db` database. You don't want to control its migrations from the local machine neither for `auth` and `remoteapp` or other apps. Other databases are not necessarily controlled by RemoteDBRouter. Therefore you start by:

```
    if db == 'remote_db':
        return False
```

The question is if you want sometimes to switch `auth` and `remoteapp` to local when you are developing write operation or if you expect only read only access and those tables need never to be created locally. Then you can add:

```
    if app_label == 'auth' or app_label == 'remoteapp':
        return False
```

Migrations for other databases can be controlled by a default router or other routers:

```
    return None
```

---

It is more complicated with tests to create a **test database** locally.

```
DATABASES = {
    'remote_db': {
        ...
        'HOST': 'some.production.host.com',
        'USER': 'some_readonly_user',   # read-only for security
        'TEST': {
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Optionally you can support read-only access to the remote db also by a router rule:

```
def db_for_write(model, **hints):
    if model._meta.app_label in ('auth', 'remoteapp'):
        return 'myapp_db'  # or maybe the db 'default' where the model doesn't exist
```

An exception is better than to harm production data if you are writing by mistake. The router can be overridden by many ways, e.g. by `using=db` parameter or  `.using(db)` method. To be safe, the connection should be by a read only user.